# Do disposable contact lenses need to be declared as "liquids"?

Tags: air-travel, health, airport-security, hand-luggage

I recently swapped over from glasses to using disposable contact lenses. I'm already [planning on carrying "travel-size" contact lens solution bottles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60370/108) to stay under the limit for liquids.

[image]

**What about the disposable contact lenses themselves though**: they come packaged in small blister packs immersed in a saline solution (usually). Does this fall under the category of "liquids" and need to be screened separately / kept in ziplock bags for being processed as a liquid?

For what it's worth, I'm flying from the UK to Myanmar via Qatar.

Comment: Where are you travelling? http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/16748718-post7.html and the whole thread is relevant. The TSA is more lenient towards medical necessities than the Brits (in general, screening in the UK is even more awful than in the US).

Comment: @chx UK to Myanmar via Qatar. That thread doesn't really answer my question though - I'm not talking about contact lens solution, I'm talking about the liquid in disposable contact lens blister packs (opening them would basically spoil the lens)

Comment: #1-#6 that thread talks about just that and a few more after.

Comment: Why not just put them in your Ziploc bag and be done with it?  If you don't, though, as I have on occasion, they'll probably not be noticed. If they are, just stick them in your bag.

Comment: I regularly travel through UK airports with these. Usually I put them in the plastic bag - you can easily get several weeks' supply in there, they're not very big - and this has never been commented on. However, I have no idea what the official position is, hence posting as a comment not an answer!

Comment: @chx Yep just noticed the rest of that thread!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Heathrow Security FAQ page says that disposable contact lenses are considered liquids and should be placed inside the transparent bag](http://www.heathrow.com/more/help-with-this-website/faqs/security-and-baggage):

> Can I carry disposable contact lenses or contact lens solution in my hand baggage?
>
> Yes, but the standard liquids rules apply. Each solution container or lens packet must have a capacity no greater than 100ml and must fit inside your transparent liquids bag.

Personally I would carry a few in my hand luggage and put most in my hold luggage. I would also declare them as liquids to avoid being questioned, swabbed and re-screened, as is usually the protocol in the UK when one forgets a liquid item outside of the transparent bag.

Comment: Interesting, I have *never* had these looked at and I hadn't thought to put them with the liquids. Maybe they don't show up well on a scanner.

Comment: I had some confiscated at Luton after they searched my bag. However, they only confiscated half of them (misssed the other packets) and they were supposed to be searching for the metal spike that showed up on the x-ray (I could see the screen highlighting the item to be examined). the metal spike was actually a folding iPad stand and would almost certainly have been confiscated if found :-)

Comment: I’m wondering if there is a risk of them popping due to the air pressure if putting them in hold luggage?

Answer (score 6):

I travel with a small number of these in my carry-on luggage within Canada and the US (usually 2 pairs as spares just-in-case).

I do not separate them out into the liquids-bag.

I have never had an issue, and they have never been separately searched.

Comment: This is not relevant to the UK! US/Canada has very different rules in this specific case.

Comment: I've flown from the UK to the US - and back again - with daily disposable contact lenses in my carry-on, and also had no issues.

Comment: Yes - but when I posted my comment the OP had not indicated where he was flying.

Comment: In the US, it's usually 3oz of liquid or more that's not allowed. The minuscule amount of liquid in these blister packs most likely is not of any concern.

Comment: The fact that *you don't* separate them doesn't mean they're not required to be separated. It just means you haven't been discovered.

Comment: Yes that's right. I simply indicated my experience and I have not made a comment as to the official requirement.

Comment: @chx it's probably relevant to the extent that it demonstrates that these things aren't generally detected by the scanners.  I have frequently forgotten some small liquid item that I've neglected to put in the bag, sometimes a couple of contact lenses, sometimes a somewhat larger but still very small bottle of something, and it has never been detected.  The largest item I recall having not been detected, or at least not acted upon, was contact lens solution, probably between 20 and 40 ml, in a 100-ml bottle.  By contrast, I have been stopped for bottles of water of around 500 ml or more.

Answer (score 6):

I think they do fall in to the liquid category and should be put in the plastic bag.

However I frequently forget that I have a pair in my handbag, so far that has never caused problems, not even in Heathrow or other UK airports. I think a few disposable lenses may simply be to small to register in the scan.

I would not recommend doing it on purpose, simply because additional security screening can take a long time. Some airports (including Heathrow) seem to have the policy that if you forget anything in your bag that you should have take out (like liquids or laptops), than your bag will be inspected more closely. Depending on how forgetful people in front of you were, you might have to wait a long time.

Answer (score 1):

(this should be a comment, but i don't have enough reputation, sorry about that)

Also be aware that some companies, like Ryanair don't allow you to take contact lenses in your checked baggage:

> You must not include in Checked Baggage money, jewellery, precious metals, keys, cameras, computers, medicines, spectacles, sunglasses, contact lenses, watches, mobile phones, personal electronic devices, negotiable papers, securities, cigarettes, tobacco or tobacco products or other valuables, business documents, passports and other identification documents or samples.

Comment: It's not that they don't allow it. Rather they are saying that if you place contact lenses (or any expensive good mentioned) in hold luggage they'll refuse to reimburse you in case of damage/theft.

Comment: @JoErNanO or of loss.